# Accessing package in python virtual environment

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv, geopandas

I have a virtual environment in which I have installed 'geopandas'. When I do a pip list it lists this package as well. But when I try to call it in my jupyter notebook via 'import geopandas' I get a ModuleNotFoundError. Please help - I'm using windows machine

Comment: Maybe your Jupyter notebook is not running in the same virtual env?

Comment: I opened a notebook using 'jupyter notebook' only within my virtualenv

Comment: Install again `python -m pip install jupyterlab` and open with this command `jupyter notebook` may be it works.

Comment: Did you try running `!pip list` from within the notebook? Does that list `geopandas`? Also, do you by any chance have any other file or module by that name lingering around in the location where you have opened a notebook?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60512093/8508004) and try `%pip install geopandas` in your notebook. That should get you past that hurdle and if it is the only package you need, then code can run. Then you can sort out your environment at your leisure.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify that your notebook is running in the correct virtual environment by doing:

```py
import sys
sys.version
```

[Here's](http://veekaybee.github.io/2020/02/18/running-jupyter-in-venv/) how to run a Jupyter notebook in a virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if your notebook is using the correct kernel (the correct virtualenv). If you are still in the kernel using your standard environment and `geopandas` is not installed, it is possible you get this error.

So check if you are working in the correct kernel:
[kernel check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QI10u.png)

You can install a kernel in jupyter notebook by activating the venv and then installing it:

```
source activate myenv
python -m ipykernel install --user --name myenv --display-name "Python (myenv)"
```

More info about this install [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernel-install).